# onDraw doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-custom-view, android-resources

I overrided RelativeLayout class by a new one:

```
public class myRelative extends RelativeLayout{
//...
//this function is called but layout is not filled
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
//...
}
```

the XML file looks like this:

```
 <myRelative
                    android:id="@+id/someid"
                    android:clipChildren="false"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
....
</....>
```

The behaviour of this Layout is the same as usual `RelativeLayout`? Why nothing changed? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `setWillNotDraw(false);` in all constructors of your custom view. Or maybe your custom view placed in xml where parent view have also `WHITE` background.

Answer (score 1):

Layouts have special optimization. If there's no background set, onDraw is not called, because layout is supposed to be an empty view. Only dispatchDraw is called every time.

Comment: In debuger onDraw is called at least one time. Do you mean this is impossible to override draw LinearLayouts ?